# Do I need to completely scrap my application to add Core Data?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am a beginner and when I first made this application (simple to-do list app) I did not know about Core Data. Now I am trying to implement Core Data but it seems like if I want to do so, I basically have to change my application completely. For example, I created a new Master Detail Application with Core Data and compared it to my current application, and basically none of it is the same.

One especially confusing part is that in my current Table View, I have two sections which get their objects from two different arrays. If I were to add Core Data, I would have no idea how to do so. Would I have to eliminate the arrays completely and only use NSFetchedResultsController? Also, in my application I have modal view controllers. In the Master Detail application it seems that Core Data only works in the Master view. I have no idea how I would implement core data in a modal view controller (which defines the values for a task object). Would I have to declare properties for all the managedObjectContext, managedObject, entityDescription, fetchRequest, etc. again in the modal view controller.h?

Here is some of my code if you care:

TableViewController.m

```
-(NSMutableArray *)taskArray {
    if (!taskArray) {
        taskArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return taskArray;
}
-(NSMutableArray *)completedArray {
    if (!completedArray) {
        completedArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return completedArray;
}
-(IBAction)changeSettings:(id)sender{
    SettingsViewController *svc = [[SettingsViewController alloc]initWithColor:baseColor];
    [svc setDelegate:self];
    [svc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self presentViewController:svc animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 cellSubclassCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];
    if (!cell)
        cell = [[cellSubclassCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"UITableViewCell"];

    if([indexPath section] == 0){
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] taskName] uppercaseString];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];
        cell.imageView.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedhighlighted.png"];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:236.0/255 green:240.0/255 blue:241.0/255 alpha:1.0f]];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = baseColor;

        NSString *detailText = [[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] timeIntervalString];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = detailText;
               [[cell detailTextLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Black" size:12]];
        [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-DemiBold" size:16]];
[cell.contentView setAlpha:1];
    } else if ([indexPath section] == 1) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [[[self.completedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] taskName] uppercaseString];

     cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:236.0/255 green:240.0/255 blue:241.0/255 alpha:1.0f]];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = baseColor;
        NSString *detailText = [[self.completedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] timeIntervalString];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = detailText;
        [[cell detailTextLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Avenir-Black" size:12]];
        [[cell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"AvenirNext-DemiBold" size:16]];
        [cell.contentView setAlpha:0.5];
    }
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlechecking:)];
    //cell.contentView
    [cell.imageView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    cell.imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    return cell;
    }
-(void)handlechecking:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)t{

        CGPoint tapLocation = [t locationInView:self.tableView];
        NSIndexPath *tappedIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:tapLocation];
        NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = nil;

        if (tappedIndexPath.section == 0) {

            NSUInteger newRowIndex = self.completedArray.count;
            [self.completedArray addObject:[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
            [self.taskArray removeObject:[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
            newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRowIndex inSection:1];

        } else {

            NSUInteger newRowIndex = self.taskArray.count;
            [self.taskArray addObject:[self.completedArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
            [self.completedArray removeObject:[self.completedArray objectAtIndex:tappedIndexPath.row]];
            newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:newRowIndex inSection:0];
        }
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[tappedIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];

}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    NSInteger num = 0;
    if (section == 0) {
        num = self.taskArray.count;
    } else {
        num = self.completedArray.count;
    }
    return num;
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 2;
}
-(void)buttonPressed:(id)sender{
    for(UIView *v in holdViewsArray){
    if(button == sender){
        [button setHighlighted:YES];
    }
    }
}
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    if (completedArray == nil){
        headerView2.hidden = YES;
        [headerView2 setNeedsDisplay];
    } else {
        headerView2.hidden = NO;
        [headerView2 setNeedsDisplay];
    }
    switch (section) {
    case 0:
            return [holdViewsArray objectAtIndex:0];
            break;
    case 1:
            return [holdViewsArray objectAtIndex:1];
            break;

    }
    return 0;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return 60.0;
            break;

        case 1:
            return 43.0;
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
-(IBAction)addCell:(id)sender{
    Properties2ViewController *pvc = [[Properties2ViewController alloc]init];
    [pvc setDelegate:self];
    [self presentViewController:pvc animated:YES completion:NULL];
    [pvc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
    }
-(void)properties2ViewControllerDidEnterPropertiesSuccesfully:(Tasks *)t{
    if (![[t taskName] isEqual: @""]) {
    [taskArray addObject:t];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    Tasks *task = [[Tasks alloc]init];
    if (indexPath.section == 0){
    task.taskName = [[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] taskName];
        task.timeInterval = [[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] timeInterval];
    task.dateCreated = [[self.taskArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] dateCreated];
    } else if (indexPath.section == 1){
        task.taskName = [[self.completedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] taskName];
        task.timeInterval = [[self.completedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] timeInterval];
        task.dateCreated = [[self.completedArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] dateCreated];
    }
   DetailViewController *dvc = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
    [dvc setTestTask:task];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath{
    if (sourceIndexPath.section == 0){
         Tasks *taskToMove = [taskArray objectAtIndex:[sourceIndexPath row]];
        if (sourceIndexPath.row > destinationIndexPath.row) {
        [taskArray insertObject:taskToMove atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
        [taskArray removeObjectAtIndex:(sourceIndexPath.row + 1)];
        }
        else if (sourceIndexPath.row < destinationIndexPath.row) {
        [taskArray insertObject:taskToMove atIndex:(destinationIndexPath.row + 1)];
        [taskArray removeObjectAtIndex:(sourceIndexPath.row)];
        }
    } else if (sourceIndexPath.section == 1){
        Tasks *completedTaskToMove = [completedArray objectAtIndex:[sourceIndexPath row]];
        if (sourceIndexPath.row > destinationIndexPath.row) {
            [completedArray insertObject:completedTaskToMove atIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
            [completedArray removeObjectAtIndex:(sourceIndexPath.row + 1)];
        }
        else if (sourceIndexPath.row < destinationIndexPath.row) {
            [completedArray insertObject:completedTaskToMove atIndex:(destinationIndexPath.row + 1)];
            [completedArray removeObjectAtIndex:(sourceIndexPath.row)];
        }
    }
}
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    if ([self isEditing]){
        for(UIView *v in holdViewsArray){
            button.hidden = YES;
        }
    } else {
        button.hidden = NO;
    }

}
-(void)loadView{
    [super loadView];
}
-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath{
    if (proposedDestinationIndexPath.section != sourceIndexPath.section)
    {
        return sourceIndexPath;
    }
    return proposedDestinationIndexPath;
}
-(void)changeBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)c{
    baseColor = c;
    [self.tableView setSeparatorColor:c];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:c];
    button.fillColor = c;
    [button setNeedsDisplay];
}
@end
```

Basically all I need to do is save the objects that are added by the user and also save the time interval specified by the user since I want to add a timer for each object (so that if the application closes, the objects are still there). Do I need a full Core Data implementation to do this? Do I even need Core Data at all? I would really appreciate some guidance since I don't know what to do at this point.

---EDIT---
Another question. Before adding Core Data I had custom delegation to send properties from my modal view controller to my table view controller. With core data do I still need these? I'm thinking that I don't but is there a way to send properties from one view controller to the next with core data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you don't have to scrap your application. However, the learning curve of Core Data is fairly steep, and reworking it into an existing app might be fairly difficult for a beginner.

Essentially, you need to set up what's called a Core Data stack. That just means that you have the right classes in place to use Core Data.

I would suggest that in your App Delegate (or a similar place), you set up an `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, an `NSPersistentStore`, and an `NSManagedObjectContext`. In Core Data terminology, a Persistent Store is essentially your database file. A Managed Object Context is the way you access objects inside that file: it functions like a scratchpad, so you can make changes to your objects and they won't be written out to the persistent store until you call `save:` on the Managed Object Context.

Have your App Delegate set up those objects when the app launches. (The Core Data Xcode project templates will help you.) Then, each view controller that accesses Core Data objects needs to know about your Managed Object Context. I would suggest that you define a property on each such view controller. Then, whenever you create a view controller, pass in the Managed Object Context (so the App Delegate passes it to the root view controller, and that view controller passes it to the next one, etc).

> One especially confusing part is that in my current Table View, I have two sections which get their objects from two different arrays. If I were to add Core Data, I would have no idea how to do so. Would I have to eliminate the arrays completely and only use NSFetchedResultsController?

You wouldn't have to, it's just a different pattern that you could use if you wanted to.

Essentially, an `NSFetchedResultsController` is a convenient way to map a Core Data query to a table view. It does a few clever things, like causing the table to automatically refresh if your Core Data objects change.

The alternative is just to run your own query (presumably in `viewDidLoad:` or `viewWillAppear:` or similar). Then you'll have an array of objects, which you can probably feed to your existing code. Look into `NSFetchRequest` for making the queries, and the method `executeFetchRequest:error:` on `NSManagedObjectContext` for actually running them.

> Another question. Before adding Core Data I had custom delegation to send properties from my modal view controller to my table view controller. With core data do I still need these? I'm thinking that I don't but is there a way to send properties from one view controller to the next with core data?

There are a number of ways you could approach that.

If each of your view controllers is editing Core Data objects in the same database, then you could just make each view controller refresh its data (i.e. perform the fetch again) whenever its view appears.

Or you could still use your delegate pattern, but have the delegate method just for triggering a fetch: it doesn't pass properties, it just says "Some content has changed, you might want to reload, OK?".

Or you could use NSFetchedResultsController, which should pick up changes automatically.

Comment: Good answer! Very complete.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit of a beginner, too. To me, it is best to start your application from CoreData. The model must be an 'image' of the persistent store (or an 'image' of a part of a store, called a *configuration*). If you have no persistent attributes (those that can be changed while the application is running and then need to be saved with the changed values after the application closes), then you don't need CoreData for that.

Comment: Ah well I guess I do have persistent attributes then. I need the timer to continually count down and save its value if the application is closed.

Comment: It's a good exercise to learn CoreData. There are a number of conceptual difficulties for someone new to data concepts, but through learning CoreData, I was able to develop a very good understanding of most of them.